# Windows Installer in WINE cannot connect to network

Tags: networking, kubuntu, wine, executable

I'm trying to install the [Spitfire Audio App](https://www.spitfireaudio.com/info/library-manager/) for use in my DAW. I can run `wine SpitfireAudioWinSetup-3.2.0.exe` and the installer wizard pops up just fine. After going through all the installation options and clicking "Install," this message pops up:

[image: Download failed: Success. Check you connection and clck 'Retry' to try downloading the files again, or click 'Cancel' to terminate setup.]

Other WINE apps (e.g. Firefox) are able to access the internet just fine, so it appears to be specific to this. I run Kubuntu 20.04 and have version 5.0 of WINE. How can I connect this installer to the internet? Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a question for AskUbuntu. Try `https://www.winehq.org/`

Comment: As above. And try to find an "offline" installer as an workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Spitfire Audio App has a garbage rating in Wine as shown in the below screenshot. Manually downloading Spitfire Audio App version 3.1.15 which  has a platinum rating works in Wine according to WineHQ.

[image]

---

To install Windows applications using Wine, follow these instructions <sup>[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)</sup> :

1. Download the Windows application from any source (e.g. download.com). Download the .exe (executable).
2. Place it in a convenient directory (e.g. the desktop or home folder).
3. Open the terminal, and `cd` into the directory where the .exe is located.
4. Type wine the-name-of-the-application.extension (e.g. `wine realplayer_installer.exe`).

This will start the .exe using Wine. If it is an installer, it should then run as it would in Windows. If the application asks for a directory to install the application to, select put it under `C:\Program Files`.

Answer (score 0):

I have spitefire working just fine with Bitwig 8 Track. Are you still having issues?
I did also install yabridge, which was a help seeing the windows VSTs in Bitwig

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1174367)